# Create a new list from selected items from a listview

Tags: android, listview

This Question has been modified to show working code.

When they click an item such as Steak, I want that item to be placed into another list.  If they then select Potatoes, that too should be added to this new list such that at the end I would have a list that shows all the items the user selected. Here is what I have so far.

LunchListMenu.java

```
package com.mycompany.lunch;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LunchListMenu extends Activity {  

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.maincoarse);
        final ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);              
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.lunch_menu,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        final ArrayList<String> myNewList = new ArrayList<String>();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {



            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {  
                String item=lv.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
                String itemordered;
                itemordered = item + " added to list";
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), itemordered, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                myNewList.add(item);                
            }
        });

                // List View Button
                Button btnLunchList = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lrList);
                btnLunchList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {                       
                        setContentView(R.layout.selecteditems);
                        ListView selecteditems = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
                        ArrayAdapter<String> newadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(LunchListMenu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myNewList);              
                        selecteditems.setAdapter(newadapter);
                    }
                });
    }
                    public void shareMyList(View v){
                        // Share Selected Items Button
                        Button btnShareItems = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shareMyList);
                        btnShareItems.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                share.setType("text/plain");
                                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I'm being sent!!");
                                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Text"));
                            }


                        });
                    }
}
```

I also created a New Layout called selecteditems.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:background="@drawable/main_background" 
  android:paddingLeft="10.0dip" 
  android:paddingTop="0.0dip" 
  android:paddingRight="10.0dip" 
  android:paddingBottom="10.0dip" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100.0dip"
            android:background="@drawable/title" />

        <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:background="@drawable/head" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="10.0dip" />    

          <ListView 
              android:id="@android:id/list"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textSize="25dip"
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:padding="10dip"
              android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

It now adds the Item to the new selecteditems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create an arrayList and put your items into it, then find your "other list" and feed that list with this arrayList.

```
 ArrayList<String> myNewList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

on your ItemClick:

```
 myNewList.add(item);
```

and then whenever you want to set your list:

```
ListView newList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_new_list);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, myNewList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
newList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: 1 thing I forgot to tell everyone... I'm New to Java/Android.  Anyway.  I tried the suggestion above.  I added final ArrayList<String> myNewList = new ArrayList<String>(); just after final ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1); in the onCreate.  I then added the remain code to the End of my onItemClick.  I am getting an error that is red underlining "new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, myNewList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);" ... Error: The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}, ArrayList<String>, int) is undefined

Comment: That's because you're in OnItemClickListener... you should send "ListMenu.this" instead of "this". But you shouldn't do those codes over there, you just need to add your item to myNewList onItemClick method. Then you should find and setAdapter your list wherever you want it to be shown ;)

Comment: My bad :) it should be like: ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListMenu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myNewList); And yes, that's what i'm talking about, you should put a listView in it and then you just need to find that listView as i mentioned before and set adapter like, now, i said.. Hope works out ;)

Comment: OK, I have almost got it.  It now adds the Item to the new selecteditems layout but if I go back to the ListMenu and choose another item, it replaces the items I had selected earlier. How can I get it to append the new item?  See the Above Code Changes and Additions.

Comment: All right, that's because you're recreating your "myNewList" array over and over again everytime you start this new activity. So it'll be empty and the item that you clicked, will be the only item of it. So you should make it global -and may be static as well- variable and when you create it, you should check whether it's null or not. if it's not null you shouldn't recreate it.

Comment: Ugggg!!!  I give up!  I copied your changes into my program and now I get other errors.  It wanted an android.R.id.list blahh , blahh, blahh.  I really appreciate your help.  you have gone above an beyond!

Comment: Ok, but the code above seems all right. And as i understand, it works fine. The only thing is that your myNewList array on ListItem.class has only one item, so it'll fill your list with that. You just need to find a way to fill that arraylist however you want. So you can try to save all items, that you want to list on selectedList, in someplace and then you can use them... ;)

Comment: yahya... I got it working, I updated the Code above to show it how I have it working.  Now I have another Question if you have time... See Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674589/send-listview-results-via-messaging-application

Answer (score 0):

Take a list:

```
public class arbysListMenu extends ListActivity {
    List<String> itemordered = null;    //  As  global
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
.
.
.
.
```

Then add item to itemordered list at time Click:

```
 @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

            //String item=lv.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();

            itemordered.add(lv.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString());

          ////  Now  FILL  another  ListView, adapter using this itemordered list

        }
        });
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I am no where near knowledgeable enough to know how to finish the code (meaning, how to fill the ListView in) I can look at code and kind of see what it does and massage it enough to do what I want, but have yet to write anything from scratch.