# Send ListView results via Messaging application

Tags: android, string, listview, android-arrayadapter, arrays

I am very new to programming.  I have an app that has several views.  The Main view shows a list such as Breakfast, Lunch & Dinner.  When a an item is selected, example Lunch, a list of lunch menu items is displayed such as Hamburger, Cheeseburger, French Fries... (this list is created from the string-array lunch_menu that is stored in \values\lunch.xml) as the user selects the items they want, it is stored in a new array called myNewList and is displayed whe the users presses the lunchList button.  All of the items are displayed that the user selected. So far, So good.  I created a android:onClick="shareMyList" in the selecteditems.xml and the button works, but does not populate my list.   I think what i need is to some how convert it to a string, this is where I need help.

Here is my Problem now....  I have my Share button, that when pressed, I would like it to automatically open the default Messaging app and populate the list from the selected items ListView.

```
package com.mycompany.lunch;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LunchListMenu extends Activity {  

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.maincoarse);
        final ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);              
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.lunch_menu,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        final ArrayList<String> myNewList = new ArrayList<String>();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {



            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {  
                String item=lv.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
                String itemordered;
                itemordered = item + " added to list";
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), itemordered, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                myNewList.add(item);                
            }
        });

                // List View Button
                Button btnLunchList = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lrList);
                btnLunchList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {                       
                        setContentView(R.layout.selecteditems);
                        ListView selecteditems = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
                        ArrayAdapter<String> newadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(LunchListMenu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myNewList);              
                        selecteditems.setAdapter(newadapter);
                    }
                });
    }
                    public void shareMyList(View v){
                        // Share Selected Items Button
                        Button btnShareItems = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shareMyList);
                        btnShareItems.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                share.setType("text/plain");
                                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I'm being sent!!");
                                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Text"));
                            }


                        });
                    }
}
```

Here is the Lunch Menu Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/main_background"
    android:paddingLeft="10.0dip" 
    android:paddingTop="0.0dip" 
    android:paddingRight="10.0dip" 
    android:paddingBottom="10.0dip" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/lrList"
            android:layout_width="72dip"
            android:layout_height="72dip"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@drawable/list" />

         <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/LunchMenuTitle"
            android:contentDescription="@string/LunchMenu"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="72dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.96"
            android:background="@drawable/lunch"
            android:paddingLeft="10.0dip"
            android:paddingRight="10.0dip" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10.0dip"
        android:background="@drawable/head"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:divider="#FFCC00"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp" >
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:background="@drawable/head" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="10.0dip" />  
</LinearLayout>
```

And Here is my selecteditems.xml Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:background="@drawable/main_background" 
      android:paddingLeft="10.0dip" 
      android:paddingTop="0.0dip" 
      android:paddingRight="10.0dip" 
      android:paddingBottom="10.0dip" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/shareMyList"
            android:layout_width="72dip"
            android:layout_height="72dip"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:onClick="shareMyList"
            android:background="@drawable/share" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/selectedItemsTitle"
            android:contentDescription="@string/LunchTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="72dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.96"
            android:background="@drawable/title"
            android:paddingLeft="10.0dip"
            android:paddingRight="10.0dip" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="10.0dip"
            android:background="@drawable/head"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />  

              <ListView
                  android:id="@android:id/list"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:divider="#FFCC00"
                  android:dividerHeight="2dp"
                  android:padding="10dip"
                  android:textColor="#ffffff"
                  android:textSize="20dip"
                  android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be the most kludgiest way of doing this, but it works.

```
package com.mycompany.lunch;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LunchListMenu extends Activity {

    String itemsordered;  

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.maincoarse);
        final ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);              
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.lunch_menu,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        final ArrayList<String> myNewList = new ArrayList<String>();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {



            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {  
                String item=lv.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
                String itemordered;
                itemordered = item + " added to list";
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), itemordered, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                myNewList.add(item);                
            }
        });

                // List View Button
                Button btnLunchList = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lrList);
                btnLunchList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {                       
                        setContentView(R.layout.selecteditems);
                        ListView selecteditems = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
                        ArrayAdapter<String> newadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(LunchListMenu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myNewList);              
                        selecteditems.setAdapter(newadapter);

                        // Get sdCard location so we can Create Dir and File
                        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                        File lunch = new File(sdCard,"Lunch");
                        lunch.mkdirs();
                        File file = new File(lunch, "Lunch.txt");
                        PrintWriter out = null;
                        try {
                            out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file));
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }  

                        // Write each string in the array
                        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
                        for (String s : myNewList) {  
                            out.println(s);  
                        }  
                        out.close();

                        // read File
                        try {
                            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                            String line;
                            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                                text.append(line);
                                text.append(',');
                                text.append(' ');
                            }
                        }
                        catch (IOException e) {
                        }
                        itemsordered = text; 
                    }
                });
    }

                    public void shareMyList(View v){
                        // Share Selected Items Button
                        Button btnShareItems = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shareMyList);
                        btnShareItems.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", itemsordered); 
                                sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
                                startActivity(sendIntent);
                            }
                        });
                    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for being this late. But yeah, surely that you need to store values in some place to reuse them... I would recommend you to use SQLite. But in your case, it's not so much necessary because you're not saving lots of values. So it can be handled as writing down to a text file as you've done.